# Comparing strings from XML in Perl?

Tags: xml, string, perl, comparison

Full disclaimer: I'm brand new to Perl, as in a week or less of experience. At work, my current project involves a process in which we take XML files representing course catalogues from various institutions and concatenate them into one file. I have a working Perl script + module that will do precisely this; however, I was hoping to add some extra functionality by checking that the merged file satisfies the following conditions:

1) Every class listing is from the same semester (this is contained in a  tag)

2) Every class listing is from the same year (this is contained in a  tag)

Here is my current subroutine that is run after the merge (the implication of this is that the issue is certainly in the below code):

```
sub check_files {
    my ($self, $file) = @_;
    my $parser;
    my $parsed;
    my @semesters;
    my @years;
    my $answer = 0;
    my $correct = 0;

    $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
    $parsed = $parser->parse_file($file);

    @semesters = $parsed->getElementsByTagName("SEMESTER");
    @years = $parsed->getElementsByTagName("YEAR");

    foreach my $semester1 (@semesters) {        
        my $semester2 = $semesters[1];

        if($semester1 ne $semester2) {
            if($semester1 ne "<SEMESTER>Do not delete this row</SEMESTER>") {
                print "Check semesters in data! $semester1 $semester2 \n\n";
                $answer += 1;
            }
        } else {
            print "Equal strings: $semester1 $semester2 \n\n";
            $correct += 1;
        }
    }

    foreach my $year1 (@years) {
        my $year2 = $years[1];

        if($year1 ne $year2) {
            if($year1 ne "<YEAR>Do not delete this row</YEAR>") {
                print "Check years in data! $year1 $year2 \n\n";
                $answer += 1;
            }           
        } else {
            print "Equal strings: $year1 $year2 \n\n";
            $correct += 1;
        }
    }

    print "Errors: $answer Correct: $correct \n\n";
    return $answer;

}
```

I check everything against element 1 rather than 0 because the first file that is concatenated is a header row (the thing that should equal "Do not delete this row"). Therefore, the "do not delete" stuff should always be element 0.

I get lots and lots of "Check semesters in data! 2013 2013" lines in the console. In fact, the only time my $correct variable increments is when the header row if condition fails. This makes me think that the string comparison is getting messed up somehow; the only explanations I can think of are pointer issues and encoding. But again, I just started Perl last week, so I really have no idea what I'm talking about. I know my code is inelegant, too, so sorry about that.

Thanks to anyone who can help, or even reads this and decides not to.

Comment: Nicely laid-out code; thank you. This `my $semester2 = $semesters[1]` is suspicious. You're comparing every element of `@semesters` to its second element. If that's truly your intention then that statement should be *before* the `for`, or rather you should iterate over the *indices* of `@semesters` and `last if $i == 1`. Also you ***must not*** compare your elements with a sample rendition. Your XML data may represent the same data in a very different way. Can you provide a copy or an example of your XML data? It's very hard to offer a solution without seeing the input

Comment: If your data is too big to post then please consider uploading it to something like [`pastebin`](http://pastebin.com), or put something here that demonstrates the problems you describe

Comment: The XML is of the following form:

`<SECTION>
...
<YEAR>Do not delete this row</YEAR>
<SEMESTER>Do not delete this row</SEMESTER>
...
</SECTION>
<SECTION>
...
<YEAR>2013</YEAR>
<SEMESTER>F</SEMESTER>
...
</SECTION>`

and so on, with each SECTION representing a course. The XML is taking a long time to paste into Pastebin but if this isn't enough to work off of, I can keep at it.

Comment: It turns out that the data is, in fact, too big for Pastebin. There's not much more to it than thousands of the thing I posted above, though.

Comment: I should add that I check against the second element because that is the element after the "do not delete" row. Theoretically, it should be equal to everything else or unequal to everything else.

Comment: Can you edit the file so that it remains well-formed XML but has only thirty or forty entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the output that you describe when I run your code against the data you've shown, but I do have a solution for you

You really need to get to understand XML data. It's nested very much like functional programming languages so the tags must be balanced, and there is always a single root node. In your data it's called `<ROOT>`, and if you look right at the end of the file there will be a closing `</ROOT>`

This code works by using an XPath expression to find all but the first `SECTION` elements, and then pulls the value of the `YEAR` and `SEMESTER` child elements from each of those and keeps a tally in a couple of hashes

I don't know what you want your subroutine to do if it finds multiple years or multiple semesters, so all this does is print a couple of summary lines. I hope you can fathom how to go on from here

```
sub check_files2 {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($file) = @_;

    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);

    my @sections = $doc->findnodes('/ROOT/SECTION[position() > 1]');
    printf "%d sections found after the first\n", scalar @sections;

    my (%years, %semesters);

    for my $section ( @sections ) {
        my $year = $section->findvalue('YEAR');
        my $semester = $section->findvalue('SEMESTER');
        ++$semesters{$semester};
        ++$years{$year};
    }

    my @years = keys %years;
    printf "%d different years: %s\n", scalar @years, "@years";

    my @semesters = keys %semesters;
    printf "%d different semesters: %s\n", scalar @semesters, "@semesters";
}
```

#### output

```
24 sections found after the first
1 different years: 2013
1 different semesters: F
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like this code does what I was trying to do with mine, except makes much better use of those LibXML functions (findnodes and findvalue were exactly what I should have used). I was aware of the structure of XML, which is why I thought it would work to just grab every semester and year since they only show up once per section--this is a much better-structured solution, though.

Comment: @jah: I'm glad to help. I assumed you didn't understand XML structure as you weren't able to create a well-formed subset of your live data. No worries

Comment: @jah: You should also learn to declare your Perl variables when they are first defined (when they get a value) and not declare them in a list at the top of your block or file. It helps `use strict` to help you and makes your code much more readable. I presume you're used to C or something similar

Comment: I'm used to Scheme and Java, with some VBA mixed in. Thanks for that tip about declaring variables when they're used. I assumed it was more readable to declare everything at the top, but that was just an assumption, of course.